# Getting error "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: invalid session id" upon running selenium script

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Below is my script, upon running my script passes but I see that not all of the methods are executed and there is an error in the console.

Error in console:

```
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
   at Selenium_testing.SearchTCOData.SearchtCOData() in C:\Users\dvemula\source\repos\Selenium testing\Selenium testing\SearchTCOData.cs:line 23
   at Selenium_testing.Login.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\dvemula\source\repos\Selenium testing\Selenium testing\login.cs:line 24
```

Code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Threading;
class LoginTCO
{
    static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    static void main()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("someurl");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Click();
        Console.WriteLine("clicked");
        driver.Quit();
    }
    private static void Click()
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".glyphicon-th-list")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".glyphicon-wrench")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".glyphicon-paste")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".idicon")).Click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with the full error logs including `WebDriverException: invalid session id`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons when this issue may occur.

1)Case when WebDriverManager is not in use and somehow chromedriver.exe binary was updated which supports chrome browser version 74 but OS having browser as 72. In this case you would need to update binary compatible to browser version.

2)When WebDriverManager is in use which downloads browser binary automatically. Its tries to download latest chromedriver binary which may not be compatible to your chrome browser installed version let say 72 (my guess). If so, in that case we have to download chromedriver binary which would be compatible to your browser version 72. For doing so, please take a reference of below line for this problem.

[Issue with Latest Chrome Driver Version 74](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/318)